# bitset c++ сдвиг

Tags: c++

```
cout << "\nВведите число с плавающей точкой: ";
double a;
cin >> a;
auto b = std::bitset<64>(*(unsigned long long*)(&a));
std::cout << "Input: " << b << '\n';
b.set(63);
unsigned long long c = b.to_ullong();
std::cout << "С мантисой: " << (*(double*)(&c)) << '\n';
std::cout << "Binary: " << b << '\n';
cout << "\nВыполнить циклический сдвиг?: (+/-) ";
char choice2;
cin >> choice2;
if (choice2 == '+') {
                cout << "В какую сторону выполнить сдвиг? (l - лево | r - право): ";
                char side;
                cin >> side;
                if (side == 'l'){
                    cout << "Насколько выполнить сдвиг? ";
                    int b_double;
                    cin >> b_double; // вводим на сколько сдвиг
                    b = b <<= b_double; // тут ошибка как я понимаю происходит
                    cout << "Converted: " << b << endl;
                    unsigned long long g = b.to_ullong();
                    std::cout << "Dec: " << (*(double*)(&g)) << '\n';  
                };
```

Не очень понимаю почему так происходит: Я ввожу к примеру 12.15, двоичный вид правильный, но когда хочу сделать к примеру сдвиг влево на 1 бит, то получаю 6.75418e+154 в десятичном виде. Как это исправить, чтобы было правильный сдвиг и вывод в десятичной сс.

Comment: а какой ответ Вы хотите увидеть после сдвига? (если что, для вещественных чисел сдвиг как бы не очень то и определен)

Comment: если вводим 12.15 и делаем сдвиг на 1 вправо то 6.75418  @KoVadim

Comment: Я думаю, Вы понимаете, что когда Вы делаете сдвиг бинарного представления числа, то знаковые биты сдвигаются в мантису и экспоненту и наоборот. То есть, получается немного бред. А какую задачу Вы решаете (сдвиг - это не задача, это Ваше решение)

Comment: Так а как правильно поступить в данном случае? ( нужен просто сдвиг на опр количество)

Comment: Сформулировать задачу. для меня сдвиг для 12.15 это скорее всего 6.075. А это просто деление на два. Или Вы прочитали, что сдвиг это быстрый способ умножить/поделить на степень два и решили использовать это?

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Числа хранятся в бинарном режиме.

Есть такая функция битового сдвига для типов `double` : `ldexp`

```
#include <math.h>

double ldexp(double x, int exp);

double d ;
d  = ldexp(d , -1); // делим пополам
d  = ldexp(d , 2); // умножаем на четыре
```

Тип `double` числа представляется как мантисса, умноженная на степень двойки.

```
мантисса * ( 2 ^ степень )
```

И по-этому любой битовый сдвиг не трогает мантиссу, и не ухудшает точность ,а всего-лишь прибавляет или уменьшает степень.

[Число двойной точности](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8)

Comment: сдвинуть на 10 - умножайте на 10???

Comment: ldexp  не является функцией битового сдвига.

Comment: Пытался понять вопрос, на всякий случай сказал... @KoVadim